# Camera stretched after deinitializing

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, google-cardboard

I am using [cardboard v1.4.1](https://github.com/googlevr/cardboard), and wanting to be able to toggle in and out of the cardboard vr. When transitioning out from cardboard the camera is stretched (I assume one of the eyes is stretched across the screen). I am using the following code that was provided in the example.

> ```
> private void StopXR()
> {
>     Debug.Log("Stopping XR...");
>     XRGeneralSettings.Instance.Manager.StopSubsystems();
>     Debug.Log("XR stopped.");
>
>     Debug.Log("Deinitializing XR...");
>     XRGeneralSettings.Instance.Manager.DeinitializeLoader();
>     Debug.Log("XR deinitialized.");
> }
> ```

What would be the best way to approach this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
void StopXR()
{
  var xrManager = XRGeneralSettings.Instance.Manager;
  if (!xrManager.isInitializationComplete)
    return; // Safety check
  xrManager.StopSubsystems();
  xrManager.DeinitializeLoader();
}
```

And if you are experiencig a distorted or stretched screen after exiting VR:

```
camera.ResetAspect();
camera.fieldOfView = defaultFov;
camera.ResetProjectionMatrix();
camera.ResetWorldToCameraMatrix();
```